# Can you choose the biomes for a Minecraft realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to get a Minecraft realm, but I don't know if I can choose the type of biome or not. I have a specific idea in my head of what I want my realm to be like, but I don't know if I can choose the biome like in single player mode new worlds or not. Can I?

Comment: Is this Java or Bedrock? Please, don't use tags randomly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure the Realms world itself, however there is a workaround.

> choose the biome like in single player mode new worlds

It looks like you already know how to do that on a Single Player world. You can create the desired Single Player world and upload it to Realms as follows:

1. Click on Minecraft Realms.
2. Select the Realm and click on Configure.
3. Click on one of the three Worlds to select it.
4. Click on the Reset button.
5. Choose a local Single Player world to upload.

The realms server will then follow the generation settings from the SP world.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for the entire world, I don't think you can, since the world generation in Minecraft is based on RNG.

Whenever the game has to generate a new world, it calls upon an algorithm known as *Perlin noise*. This algorithm outputs a pseudo-random value that is then used to determine the characteristics and features of the world. However, the algorithm always outputs the same value each time for a constant starting point (the **seed**). Thus, the same seed generates the same terrain every time.

Moreover, you don't generate the entire world at spawn time.
Chunks generate around players when they first enter the world. As they wander around the world, new chunks generate as needed.

The only way to "choose" biomes, I think, is finding a world you like, obtain its seed (maybe using some online database or a [seed picker](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_picker)) and upload that world on your realm.

<sub>Source: [Seed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)) and [Chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk).</sub>